# infinite centroid for kmeans spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, infinite, centroid

(i think i am almost sure what the answer is)

here is my code:

```
val fileName = """file:///home/user/data/csv/sessions_sample.csv"""
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(fileName)

// calculate input for kmeans
val input1 = df.select("id", "duration", "ip_dist", "txr1", "txr2", "txr3", "txr4").na.fill(3.0)
val input2 = input1.map(r => (r.getInt(0), Vectors.dense((1 until r.size - 1).map{ i =>  r.getDouble(i)}.toArray[Double])))
val input3 = input2.toDF("id", "features")

// initiate kmeans
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(100).setSeed(1L).setFeaturesCol("features").setPredictionCol("prediction")
val model = kmeans.fit(input3)
val model = kmeans.fit(input3.select("features"))

// Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(input3.select("features"))
val predictions = model.transform(input3)
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()

// i get an error when i run this line
val silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Number of clusters must be
>   greater than one.   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.SquaredEuclideanSilhouette$.computeSilhouetteScore(ClusteringEvaluator.scala:416)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator.evaluate(ClusteringEvaluator.scala:96)
>   ... 49 elided

But my centroids look like this:

```
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

> [3217567.1300936914,145.06533614203505,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity]

i think that beceause some centers are infinite => kmeans is unstable => silhouette  measure goes wrong.
But it still doesnt answer why, if i try to change k, any k > 1 so far, i have an error saying "Number of clusters must be greater than one".

please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I once saw the same message. The root cause is that every data is the same (my data is generated by a program) so of course there is only one cluster. BTW, I did not check its centers so I am not sure whether my case is the same as yours.